# JQuery dialog "Close" button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Normally a JQuery UI dialog looks like shown in the [official documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). I'm putting a dialog into a source code which already has a lot of JavaScript, and there are some changes to the dialog. One change is that the close button no longer shows up as "X", but rather show up as "Close".

How can I start looking into whether I can change it back to "X"?

Comment: are you including jQuery UI CSS file?

Comment: @koala_dev No, I'm only using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.

Comment: That's jQuery core, you need jQuery UI's javascript and CSS files, check the "Quick Access" section in the footer of http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Oh I see, I'm also using `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js`, so I guess just missing the CSS.

Comment: @koala_dev Yep, missing CSS indeed - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From  your comments it is clear that you're missing to add **`jQuery.UI.css` and `jQuery UI.js`**.  So add it it will work correctly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   
         href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

and it js file like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
```

You can check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hren3/) for reference.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm also using `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js`, so I guess just missing the CSS.

Comment: @MikaH. `jQuery.min.js` -- Core jQuery library file.  whereas `jQueryUI.js` --- an UI Library depends on the core file.

Comment: @MikaH. Exactly, you're missing css, beware of the script order: 1. `jQuery.js` 2. `jQueryUI.js`

Answer (score 16):

You can pass the close button text as an option:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ closeText: "hide" });
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText

Comment: THIS is the answer I was looking for! Despite it's not really well suited to the question above, that's the best way to control the close text button since the dialog initialization. There are plenty of answers here on SO about this particular topic, but they just waste time changing data AFTER inizialization.

Comment: Yes, worked for me. I wanted an "x" and I got one. Then in my .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar class I added "text-align: right;" and it put the X over at the right.